# XML Declaration standalone="yes" lxml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an xml I am parsing, making some changes and saving out to a new file. It has the declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>` which I would like to keep. When I am saving out my new file I am loosing the `standalone="yes"` bit. How can I keep it in?
Here is my code:

```
templateXml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<package>
  <provider>Some Data</provider>
  <studio_display_name>Some Other Data</studio_display_name>
</package>"""

from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(templateXml)

xmlFileOut = '/Users/User1/Desktop/Python/Done.xml'   

with open(xmlFileOut, "w") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding='UTF-8'))
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can pass `standalone` keyword argument to `tostring()`:

```
etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding='UTF-8', standalone=True)
```

Comment: TypeError: tostring() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xml_declaration'

Comment: @ArnoldRoa are you using `lxml.etree`?

Answer (score 13):

Specify `standalone` using [tree.docinfo.standalone](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.DocInfo-class.html).

Try following:

```py
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(templateXml).getroottree() # NOTE: .getroottree()

xmlFileOut = '/Users/User1/Desktop/Python/Done.xml'   

with open(xmlFileOut, "w") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True,
                           encoding=tree.docinfo.encoding,
                           standalone=tree.docinfo.standalone))
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer worked like a charm, I just thought @alecxe answer was easier to implement for me, thanks anyway for your answer, it's good to have options.

Comment: No, not okay.  This is the answer that doesn't invent data.

Comment: @juanitogan, Sorry, I don't get what you mean. Could you give more information?

Comment: @falsetru - What I mean is that it is not okay that the OP chose the other answer as correct. Yours is more correct because it doesn't override input values with hard-coded values. [This you know -- I'm just talking to everybody else.] The other answer is easier to implement ONLY because it requires fewer keystrokes on a single line, and is just lazy programming more prone to contribute to issues at some point.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show the `standalone='no'` argument in your XML header, you have to set it to `False` instead of 'no'. Just like this:

```py
etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding='UTF-8', standalone=False)
```

If not, standalone will be set to 'yes' by default.

Comment: Standalone='no' didn't work. False worked

Answer (score 0):

```
etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Will add the declaration if you're using lxml, however I noticed their declaration uses semi-quotes instead of full quotes.

You can also get the exact declaration you want by just concatenating the output with a static string you need:

```
xml = etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True, encoding='UTF-8')
xml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n' + xml
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to disable outputting `standalone` at all pass `None` instead of `True` or `False`. Sounds logical but took some time to actually find and test it.

```
etree.tostring(tree, xml_declaration = True, encoding='utf-8', standalone=None)
```

or using context manager and stream `etree.xmlfile` serialization:

```
with etree.xmlfile(open('/tmp/test.xml'), encoding='utf-8') as xf:
    xf.write_declaration(standalone=None)
    with xf.element('html'):
        with xf.element('body'):
            element = etree.Element('p')
            element.text = 'This is paragraph'
            xf.write(element)
```