# python xml version missing

Tags: python, xml

i am using python xml to update some xml date
i have small problem ,when i update the xml it cant write xml version
this is my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'c:\users\g\desktop\IT_ADMINVersionTrack.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for country in root.findall('dtModule'):
  f = country.find('FolderName').text
  print "FOLDER:",f
  v = country.find('Version').text
  print "OLD VERSION:",v
  if v == "11.0":        
    country.find('Version').text = "12.0"
    v2 = country.find('Version').text
    print "NEW VERSION",v2
  else:        
    print "NO CHANGE IN VERSION"

tree.write(r'c:\users\g\desktop\output.xml')
```

input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dsModule>
<dtModule>
<ModuleName>IT_ADMIN</ModuleName>
<Version>11.0</Version>
<FolderName>IT_ADMIN\ItDataCompInterface.dll.gz</FolderName>
<Type>P</Type>
<ClientId />
<Destination />
</dtModule>
</dsModule>
```

output xml:

```
<dsModule>
<dtModule>
<ModuleName>IT_ADMIN</ModuleName>
<Version>12.0</Version>
<FolderName>IT_ADMIN\ItDataCompInterface.dll.gz</FolderName>
<Type>P</Type>
<ClientId />
<Destination />
</dtModule>
</dsModule>
```

xml version is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The default option for `write` is actually:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write)

```
write(file, encoding="us-ascii", xml_declaration=None, default_namespace=None, method="xml")
```

However, this will still be problematic as some versions of `xml.etree` require the encoding to be supplied. Hence, to have the XML version be visible in your output file, your last line of code should read:

```
tree.write('output.xml', xml_declaration=True, method='xml', encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> tag works .but my out format of the xml is <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>  i want  "standalone="yes"" instance of "encoding='utf-8'".

Comment: @user3033339: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173983/xml-declaration-standalone-yes-lxml