# Modify XML declaration with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, minidom

I have an XML document for which I need to add a couple of things to the XML declaration using minidom. The declaration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
```

I know how to change or add attributes using minidom, which will not work here.

What is the easiest way of doing this? For reference, I am running python 3.3.3.

Comment: Can you show us your code about changing or adding attributes usiing minidom? And what kind of error it raise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be done with minidom. But you could try `lxml`.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("test.xml")
string = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(), pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, standalone = False, encoding = "UTF-16")
with open("test2.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(string)
```

More or less taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173983/xml-declaration-standalone-yes-lxml).

Comment: Interesnting, pretty straight forward. However, the test2.xml I get has `standalone='yes'`, any thoughts on that?

Comment: It has to be `standalone = False` instead of `standalone = "no"`. Then it works for me.