# In Python using etree how do I retain the doc type and declaration

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an xml file that I'm adding to daily. The problem is when I read the file in then save it loses the xml declaration at the top of the file. The code I'm using:

```
def parseXML():

    xmlFile = open(myfile,'r')
    parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
    tree = etree.parse(xmlFile, parser)
    return tree

xml_curr = parseXML()
xml_root = xml_curr.getroot()
```

I then append to this:

```
xml_root.append(new_elements)
```

Apologies if this doesn't quite make sense, python is new to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Declaration standalone="yes" lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173983/xml-declaration-standalone-yes-lxml)

Comment: I need to append to the XML and I cant see how to do that on the other thread. I've edited my question

Comment: `strip_cdata=False` implies that you use lxml rather than ElementTree. In any case, the code is incomplete. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding='UTF-8', standalone="yes")
```

Comment: Thanks but I think if I convert it to a string I cant append to it. I need to add new elements into the file and Im doing this using: etree.Subelement(...) then xml_root.append(...)