# Script to parse xml files removes first line

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, lxml

Script to parse xml files removes first line
Here is the python script which I have to sort the uuids for multiple .xml files:

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

inputpath = 
xsltfile = 
outpath = 

dir = []

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
    structure = os.path.join(outpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    if not os.path.isdir(structure):
        os.mkdir(structure)
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.xml')):
            dir = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            print(dir)
            dom = ET.parse(dir)
            xslt = ET.parse(xsltfile)
            transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
            newdom = transform(dom)
            outfile = open(structure + "\\" + filename, 'a')
            outfile.write(ET.tostring(newdom,pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Here is the .xslt template which im using against multiple .xml files

Comment: like @joao is referring in his answer, see for more options this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18174094/3710053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first line is called the XML declaration, and by default, `etree.tostring()` does not output it, you need to add the `xml_declaration=True` argument, see the  [lxml docs](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have added this line in the python code and its working fine ```outfile.write(ET.tostring(newdom,pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True,encoding='UTF-8',standalone='yes').decode())``` .  but this is giving the output with single quotes ```<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>``` . Can I know what should I change to get the the values in double quotes? l mean like this ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>```

Comment: I don't think there's an option for that, single and double quotes are equally legal in XML.

Comment: Hie Joao, I'm getting this new error which i added in the question. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: That's a totally different issue, please ask a separate question. Stack Overflow goes to a lot of trouble to ensure good quality questions and answers, and doing this does not help: now the contents of your question no longer match the title, and the question I answered is no longer asked, this has become incomprehensible. Please revert.

Comment: Okay, i just reverted. Here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67643676/python-script-to-parse-xml-files-and-sort-the-uuids