# Python Script to parse xml files and sort the uuids

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Here is the python script which I have to sort the uuids for multiple .xml files:

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

inputpath = 
xsltfile = 
outpath = 

dir = []

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
    structure = os.path.join(outpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    if not os.path.isdir(structure):
        os.mkdir(structure)
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.xml')):
            dir = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            print(dir)
            dom = ET.parse(dir)
            xslt = ET.parse(xsltfile)
            transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
            newdom = transform(dom)
            outfile = open(structure + "\\" + filename, 'a', encoding="utf-8")
            outfile.write(ET.tostring(newdom,pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True,standalone='yes').decode())
```

I see this error when trying to parse multiple .xml files

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python.py", line 23, in <module>
outfile.write(ET.tostring(newdom,pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True,encoding='UTF-8',standalone='yes').decode())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 19935-19939: character maps to <undefined>
```

The above error appears ONLY when i pass **encoding='UTF-8'** in py file

Comment: maybe you have file which use different encoding - ie. `Latin1`, `CP1250` (popular on Windows)

Comment: did you check what you have in file in position 19935-19939 ?

Comment: error shows that it try to use encoding `cp1252` - maybe you should use it.

Comment: Hi Furas, Thanks for your response. I see that source file in encoded with 'utf-8' like other files. and that files doesnt have 19935 lines.

Comment: it is not `line` but `chars` position

Comment: maybe your system uses `CP1250` as default encoding and you should manually set correct encoding `open(..., encoding="utf-8')`

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that, I'm not even using ```open``` in my python code. I'm using for loop to parse each file. I'm afraid i cant include open in there.

Comment: it seems you don't know your own code - you already use `open` - see line `outfile = open(...)`. Problem is not when you `read` data but when you `write` data - `outfile.write(...)`. And problem should resolve `outfile = open(..., encoding="utf-8')`

Comment: i thought you meant open when parsing the file. anyway i just updated the code and i still see the same issue. In the output .xml file I see its transforming to ```<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII' standalone='yes'?>```

Comment: I want this to be as source file which is ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>```

Comment: you may have two different problems with `UTF-8`. First `<?xml ...encoding='ASCII'...` and it needs `encoding="utf-8"` in `tostring(..., encoding="utf-8)`, second `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' ` and it needs `encoding="utf-8` in `open(..., encoding="utf-8)`

Comment: Ya, this is working. Thanks for your support @furas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the python code which is running fine

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET
import sys


inputpath = "C:\\projects\\xmlformat\\uuid\\"
xsltfile = "C:\\projects\\xmlformat\\uuid\\uuid.xslt"
outpath = "C:\\projects\\xmlformat\\output"

dir = []

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    unicode = str

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
    structure = os.path.join(outpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    if not os.path.isdir(structure):
        os.mkdir(structure)
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.xml')):
            dir = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            print(dir)
            dom = ET.parse(dir)
            xslt = ET.parse(xsltfile)
            transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
            newdom = transform(dom)
            infile = unicode(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True,standalone='yes',encoding="UTF-8").decode())
            outfile = open(structure + "\\" + filename, 'a',encoding="UTF-8")
            outfile.write(infile)
```